# Why isn't my favicon working?

Tags: favicon

Now I know there are a lot of similar questions around SO but I think I've covered all the basics. Here's what I know:

My favicon is accessible through /favicon.ico ([full link](http://www.bandcmotors.co.uk/favicon.ico))

The HTML is ([page URL](http://www.bandcmotors.co.uk)):

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.bandcmotors.co.uk/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.bandcmotors.co.uk/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I've tried relative and absolute versions too. No love.

The HTTP response headers:

```
Date: Mon, 22 Dec 2008 15:07:34 GMT
Server: Cherokee
Etag: 494bc264=57e
Last-Modified: Fri, 19 Dec 2008 15:48:52 GMT
Content-Type: image/x-icon
Content-Length: 1406

200 OK
```

The icon loads fine in a browser and I've cleared my cache but I still can't see the icon in the address bar or tab. On either Firefox or IE.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Edit 1. I used [a validator](http://www.html-kit.com/favicon/validator/) and it rather helpfully told me that it could not download it. Rather odd considering I can download it fine... If anybody could explain that, it might help fix the problem.

Edit 2. I just drop-kicked my computer, restarted and it all worked. I hate caches that refuse to clear themselves properly ****grumbles**** >=(

Comment: Strange... it works fine for me in FF and IE7

Comment: Add `?` at the end of your link, like so: `href="http://www.bandcmotors.co.uk/favicon.ico?"` and reset your cache before testing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a gif or png?  The [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) cites the following:

> However, the format for the image you have chosen must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors. The format of the image must be one of PNG (a W3C standard), GIF, or ICO

Does your image conform?  Have you tried using other favicons?

Answer (score 3):

it works fine, your browser is probably caching it for some reason.

Btw., ETags are not recommended in such situations, better just use an "Expires: " header ...

Answer (score 1):

It works fine in my safari browser, even in windows... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the relative path to the icon, not the full "http://...." address? For example:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Another suggestion would be removing the type attribute:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

I can see it in Firefox and Opera too, as is.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with your hosting provider (if applicable). GoDaddy & other popular hosting providers cache certain details & refresh your "virtual server" about once per hour.