# Can't get favicon to display no matter what I do

Tags: favicon

I do realize there's 50 other questions like this, but nothing works for some reason. All links below are to the actual site in question to keep everything as clear as possible.

I uploaded my favicon here:

http://fantasy-premier.com/favicon.ico

Uploading the icon to the home directory used to be enough for it to show up in most browsers, but not anymore it seems. So I took the advice of some SO answers and put this in the header, first with a relative path but now with an absolute one to make sure I'm hitting the right URL (because there's a lot of `.htaccess` SEO action on the site):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.fantasy-premier.com/favicon.ico"/>
```

I tried using `http://` but switched to `//` to make sure it's not an issue with `https`. I then saw a different answer and switched to

```
<link rel="icon" href="//www.fantasy-premier.com/favicon.ico"/>
```

Still nothing. It's been about 3 days of attempts now, this last version has been on the site for more than 24 hours, so it's certainly not a case of "wait a while or clear the cache". Speaking of which, I have cleared the cache and tried different browsers. So, how do I get this icon to finally show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the favicon using Google Chrome 36, but maybe you should try to convert the .ico to .png and then follow the W3 guide:

http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried all of the different HTML options for referencing the icon, then perhaps there's a problem with the icon itself.

Check that the icon file is actually an icon file (i.e. not just a PNG or other image file type renamed to have a `.ico` file extension).

Try taking another .ico file from a website that works, and saving it on yours to see whether that works.

There are multiple tools online for creating `.ico` files from other image types. A quick Google search yields http://www.rw-designer.com/image-to-icon for example.

Comment: I used one of the online tools, which I've used for several other sites in the past and it worked for those other ones.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386828/why-isnt-my-favicon-working?rq=1